# Determine the destination (register name or address) and value

Tags: assembly, x86

```
mov eax 0x8000 

mov ebx 0x10000

lea esp, [ebx+eax*2]
```

Here I know that the destination is esp. Also I know the LEA (load effective address) behaves like move in this situation. But I am no sure about value stored at this register. I see it this way:

> 0x8000 * 2 = 0x80000
>
> 0x20000 + 0x10000 = 0x200000

so the value would be:

> [0x200000]

am I right?

Comment: 0x8000*2 is 0x10000, not 0x80000. Anyway, personally I would say that the value is `0x20000` (without the brackets). Saying `[0x20000]` could be interpreted as meaning _the value at address 0x20000_.

Comment: @Michael if i had used mov [ebx] , eax after mov ebx 0x10000 would it change anything? I see it that way - store 0x8000 at address 0x10000 which in neither address of eax nor ebx, so it wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your arithmetic but, generally, you are right. You understand the x86 LEA instruction correctly.

The x86 LEA instruction does not dereference the address it computes. That is, LEA does not go to the address; rather, LEA merely computes the address for later use by another instruction.